# Acessar valores JSON via PHP

Tags: php, json, array

Senhores,

Estou tentando acessar os valores que estão dentro da casa "values", recuperando o value e o odd porém sem sucesso, estou criando assim:

```
$json = json_decode($response);
foreach ($json->response as $item) {
echo $item->league->name . '<br>';
echo $item->league->country . '<br>';

foreach($item->bookmakers as $bets){
    echo ' - ' . $bets->id . ' - ' . $bets->name . '<br>';
    foreach ($bets->values as $odds) {
        echo $odds->value;
        echo $odds->odd;
    }
  }
}
```

meu json

```
"response": [ {
            "league": { 
            "id": 562,
            "name": "Reserve League",
            "country": "Belarus",
            "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/562.png",
            "flag": "https://media.api-sports.io/flags/by.svg",
            "season": 2020
         },
         "fixture": {
                     "id": 430126,
                     "timezone": "UTC",
                     "date": "2020-05-15T10:30:00+00:00",
                     "timestamp": 1589538600
          },
         "update": "2020-05-15T09:49:33+00:00",
        "bookmakers": [
                  {
                       "id": 6,
                       "name": "Bwin",
                       "bets": [
                               {
                                   "id": 1,
                                   "name": "Match Winner",
                                   "values": [
                                              {
                                                  "value": "Home",
                                                  "odd": "1.90"
                                              },
                                              {
                                                  "value": "Draw",
                                                  "odd": "4.10"
                                              },
                                              {
                                                  "value": "Away",
                                                  "odd": "2.95"
                                              }
                                        ]
                                     }....
```

Onde posso estar errando?

Obrigado.

Comment: Acho que vale a pena você postar o seu `JSON` em forma de texto aqui. Apesar de não ser muito grande, da forma que está você precisa que outro usuário digite ele inteiro para poder simular o seu problema.

Comment: Editada a pergunta com o JSON

Comment: Você tem que quer utilizar um `for` em *bets*, que está dentro de *bookmakers*

Comment: No caso @ValdeirPsr seria desta maneira for($bets = 0; $bets < count($item->bookmakers); $bets++){
   echo $bets;
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao nomear a variável de `$item->bookmakers as $bets` você se confundiu - $bets não é o campo bets do se json, é um item da lista bookmakers. Como o Valdeir comentou, faltou o `for` em bets, dessa maneira:

```
$json = json_decode($response);
foreach ($json->response as $item) {
echo $item->league->name . '<br>';
echo $item->league->country . '<br>';

foreach($item->bookmakers as $betsy){
    echo ' - ' . $betsy->id . ' - ' . $betsy->name . '<br>';
    foreach ($betsy->bets as $odds) {
        foreach($odds->values as $o){
            echo $o->value;
            echo $o->odd;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Foi isso mesmo @Fred obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

tenho um problema parecido aqui, mas está um pouco mais fundo na cadeia do json, saco alguém consiga me ajudar.

esse é meu json

```
 [
{
    "id": "eb5274457814f2cc586fc6f7bb4f5640",
    "has_outrights": true,
    "sport_key": "americanfootball_nfl_super_bowl_winner",
    "sport_title": "NFL Super Bowl Winner",
    "commence_time": "2023-02-12T23:30:00Z",
    "home_team": null,
    "away_team": null,
    "bookmakers": [
        {
            "key": "unibet",
            "title": "Unibet",
            "last_update": "2022-07-05T15:44:14Z",
            "markets": [
                {
                    "key": "outrights",
                    "outcomes": [
                        {
                            "name": "Buffalo Bills",
                            "price": 7.5
                        },
                      
                        {
                            "name": "Atlanta Falcons",
                            "price": 201.0
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Houston Texans",
                            "price": 301.0
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
```

Gostaria de retorna por echo os valores do **outcomes**. tudo que tentei não consegui retorna nada, até usando o exemplo do amigo acima, ainda não sei onde estou errando.